# Which of the following predicate logic is true?

Tags: predicate-logic, first-order-logic

$$S_1: \forall x (f(x) \rightarrow g(x)) \Leftrightarrow \forall x f(x) \rightarrow \forall x g(x)$$

$$S_2: \exists x (f(x) \rightarrow g(x)) \Leftrightarrow \forall x f(x) \rightarrow \exists x g(x)$$

---

I got $S_2$ true but for $S_1$, I think only reverse implication exists but not the forward implication.

Am I doing something wrong here ?

Comment: Consider the difference between these statements: (a) every natural number that is a multiple of 2 is a multiple of 4; (b) if every natural number is a multiple of 2, then every natural number is a multiple of 4.  Which one is true?

Comment: You may also want to consider that (material) implication is a close relative of disjunction.  What do you know about the distributivity of quantifiers over disjunction?

Comment: More specifically, in $S_2$, replace $f(x) \to g(x)$ with $\lnot f(x) \lor g(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, for the first one the forward implication *does* hold, and the reverse does *not*:

Proof for forward:

1. $\forall x (f(x) \rightarrow g(x))$  (Premise)
2. $\qquad \forall x f(x)$ (Assumption)
3. $\qquad \qquad a$ (Consider any 'a')
4. $\qquad \qquad f(a) \rightarrow g(a)$ ($\forall$ Elim 1)
5. $\qquad \qquad f(a)$ ($\forall$ Elim 2)
6. $\qquad \qquad g(a)$ ($\rightarrow$ Elim 2)
7. $\qquad \forall x g(x)$ ($\forall$ Intro 3-6)
8. $\forall x f(x) \rightarrow \forall x g(x)$ ($\rightarrow$ Intro 2-7)

Counterexample for reverse implication:

Domain: Natural Numbers

$f(x)$: x is an even number

$g(x)$ : x is an odd number

Then $\forall x f(x) \rightarrow \forall x g(x)$ is true (since the antecedent is false), but $\forall x (f(x) \rightarrow g(x))$ is false.

For the second one:

$\exists x (f(x) \rightarrow g(x)) \Leftrightarrow$ (Implication)

$\exists x (\neg f(x) \lor g(x)) \Leftrightarrow$ (Distribution $\exists$ over $\lor$)

$\exists x \neg f(x) \lor \exists x g(x) \Leftrightarrow$ (Quantifier Negation)

$\neg \forall x  f(x) \lor \exists x g(x) \Leftrightarrow$ (Implication)

$\forall x f(x) \rightarrow \exists x g(x)$

Comment: Can you please show how the forward implication exists and why not reverse exists by using the approach you have shown for second one ?

Comment: @Garrick I can't do that, because for the second one I used equivalence principles, so if I were to do that for the first, I would show those two statements to be equivalent, which they are not, So, I have to use inference rules ... Or some other method yet.

Comment: Yeah. I got it . Thanks again for a good explaination !!